# Importing self-made package functions into the right namespace

Tags: python

I have a package like this:

```
mypack/
    __init__.py [an empty file]
    functions.py
```

The contents of `functions.py`is:

```
def myfunction():
    import sqlite3
    db = sqlite3.connect('db.sqlite3')
```

From a jupyter notebook I do this:

```
import sqlite3
from mypack import functions
functions.myfunction()
```

This throws this error:

```
NameError: name 'sqlite3' is not defined
```

As you can see, I am importing `sqlite3` both in the function, and in the notebook. What is the other way that I should be doing this to import `sqlite3` so that `myfunction` can access it?

Comment: you dont need to import sqlite3 in notebook. Importing it in functions.py will be sufficient.

Comment: At the top of functions.py?

Comment: Yes you can add it at the top in file or in myfunction() as well